# Update Django model instance using POST method using Serialzer

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I trying to update a instance model if it exists using serializer, but I got error
any ideas?

views.py

````
def sensor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        sensor = Sensor.objects.filter(name=data['name'])

        if sensor.exists():
            serializer = SensorDetailSerializer(instance=sensor, data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            else:
                return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

        else:
            serializer = SensorDetailSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            else:
                return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)```


AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
[12/Apr/2020 13:13:19] "POST /sensor/ HTTP/1.1" 500 87980
````

Comment: could you share your related serializers and models

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a queryset instead of an actual instance to your serializer (hence the error you're getting `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'`).

You could update your code to do something similar to this:

```
def sensor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        # Fetches the first result of Sensor with name data['name']
        sensor = Sensor.objects.filter(name=data['name']).first()

        if sensor:
            serializer = SensorDetailSerializer(instance=sensor, data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            else:
                return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

        else:
            serializer = SensorDetailSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            else:
                return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: [henriquesalvaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8658654/henriquesalvaro)  thanks it was a success, I highly appreciate your help. I worked perfectly